# How to cast to a generic list from the lambda expression result

Tags: linq

I have a class structure like below.

```
ObservableCollection<Group> deviceCollection = new ObservableCollection<Group>();
public class Group 
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }       
    public List<TargetSelectionStructure> TargetCollection { get; set; }
}
public class TargetSelectionStructure
{
    public string ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsGroup { get; set; }
}
```

From the observable collection object deviceCollection. I need to get the collection which matches with IsGroup property as false. So I have written like

```
var currentStruct = deviceCollection.Where(d => d.TargetCollection.Any(t => t.IsGroup == false));
```

Now the currentStruct should contain the collection basically `List<TargetSelectionStructure>`. I am unable to cast the currentStruct to the type of `List<TargetSelectionStructure>`.
How can I solve this?

Comment: use the `ToList()` Extension Method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx, or, just press `.` and use intellisense. There must be a least one duplicate for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't cast it, because `currentStruct` is an `IEnumerable<Group>`.

I think you query needs to look like this:

```
var currentStruct = deviceCollection.SelectMany(x => x.TargetCollection)
                                    .Where(x => !x.IsGroup).ToList();
```

This returns all `TargetSelectionStructure` instances from all `Group`s that have `IsGroup == false`.

Your question is not entirely clear. It is possible to interpret your question in a second way: You want to have all `TargetSelectionStructure` instances from a `Group` if at least one of them has `IsGroup == false`.
To achieve this, you would use this query:

```
var currentStruct = deviceCollection.Where(x => x.TargetCollection
                                                 .Any(y => !y.IsGroup))
                                    .SelectMany(x => x.TargetCollection)
                                    .ToList();
```